# cannot download calico on kubernetes cluster

Tags: centos, kubernetes, calico

I am trying to set up a kubernetes cluster on centos, and installing calico is one of the steps.
My control plane is ready, but `coredns` are still pending.

From the internet, i got the below command to install calico on the network
`curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O`

But when i open the file, it says `Redirecting to https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/manifests/calico.yaml`

then i ran `curl https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/manifests/calico.yaml -O`
This downloaded a file, but when i run `kubectl apply -f calico.yaml`
I get the below error
`error: error parsing calico.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 19: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

so i pasted the calico file from this link `https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml` and ran `kubectl apply -f calico.yaml`
and got this error

```
error: resource mapping not found for name: "calico-kube-controllers" namespace: "kube-system" from "calico.yaml": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

From where and how can i get the correct calico file.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the right file - depending on what version you're using - on [github](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/tree/release-v3.26).

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/getting-started/kubernetes/self-managed-onprem/onpremises) for "Install Calico networking and network policy for on-premises deployments" the first step is to install the operator on your cluster:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.1/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
```

and then download the custom resources:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.1/manifests/custom-resources.yaml -O

kubectl create -f custom-resources.yaml

watch kubectl get pods -n calico-system
```

Alternatively, the users in the [calico slack channel](https://calicousers.slack.com/) might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Kubernetes are you running? The `PodDisruptionBudget` v1 API was introduced in Kubernetes `v1.21`, so it requires that release at a minimum.

This could be a simple fix by just running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubectl kubeadm
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```